# How to take a pull of a remote branch that has not been merged into master into a local branch?

Tags: git, pull

There is a remote branch and I want to take a pull from that branch into one of my local branches. How do I do that?

What is wrong with this?

```
git checkout myLocalBranch
git pull remoteBranch myLocalBranch
```

Comment: The first argument to `git pull` has to be a remote, not a branch - try `git pull origin myLocalBranch`, replace `origin` with your remote name

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is used to update your current branch to the latest version on the remote. You can't just pull a branch into another one. That's called merging!

So you have to do this:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/remoteBranch
```

and resolve the merge conflicts (if any). This will result in the state you asked for: your local branch will have the remote branch on top.

As @eckes pointed out in the comments (thanks!) you should first run `git fetch origin` in order to tell git about `remoteBranch`.

Comment: nitpicking: `pull` = `fetch` + `merge`, so he'd have to `git fetch origin && git merge origin/remoteBranch`

Answer (score 0):

First lets see where your commands can be improved.

```
git checkout myLocalBranch
```

is used to switch to an existing branch named myLocalBranch. If myLocalBranch does not exist then it will result in an error.

```
git pull remoteBranch myLocalBranch
```

Cannot be used to arbitrarily pull from any branch to any branch. Syntax for pull command is the following where some-remote is generally 'origin' or any other configured remote repository.

```
git pull <some-remote> myLocalBranch
```

will pull the branch on remote which is being tracked by myLocalBranch.

---

Coming to your problem which is to pull a specific branch from remote. So, you need to create a local branch, specify the remote repository and the remote branch which has to be tracked.

```
git checkout -b myLocalBranch origin/remoteBranch
```

Will create a new local branch with name myLocalBranch which will track remoteBranch of 'origin' repository. Now you have switched to myLocalBranch and the branch has been configured. Do a `git pull` which pull your work from remote.